# ParseException trying to format date prior to insertion into database

Tags: java, jdbc

I am connecting to an Access 2010 database from eclipse using a jdbc:odbc connection.  I wrote a method to format date values before inserting them into a table in the database.  However, the stack trace is printing out the following when I try to run it:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "dateString"
```

Here is the line of code that calls the method, and which is firing the error:

```
ps.setDate(5,formatDate("10/1/2013"));//For October 1, 2013
```

Here is the method itself:

```
static Date formatDate(String dateString){
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = null;
    try{
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        java.util.Date parsed = format.parse("dateString");
        sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
    }
    catch(ParseException pe){pe.printStackTrace();}
        return sqlDate;
    }
```

Can someone show me how to fix this so that the data is parsed correctly before insertion into the MS Access database?

Comment: Euh `format.parse(dateString);`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't know why I did not see that.  Perhaps because I spent the past few weeks in a different language.  Thank you for the second set of eyes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: could I ask you to consider casting a close vote on this question? This is a classic typo/unrepro and it would be best closed/removed IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes from the parse method so that its using the `dateString` variable rather than a `String` literal

```
Date parsed = format.parse(dateString);
```